# Excel matching multiple partial values

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I've posted an example image showing what I want to achieve. I want to match partial values from row D in row A. When there is a match it should return the value from D. I have words that can have multiple partial matches (for example 'summer dress' and 'dress' are both partial match for 'XXL Summer dress') I thought I'd order row D from most characters to least to get the best match.

Normally I'd use multiple IF functions, but in my file column A contains 30.000 values and I have 300 values in row D, which makes the formula too big I guess.

Is it possible to get the results as shown in the image for these amounts of values?

[image: https://ibb.co/ygrTDkb]

I've tried VLOOKUP / INDEX & MATCH and some macros, but none seem to return the value I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=INDEX(D:D,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW($D$3:$D$6)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$3:$D$6,A3))),1))
```

This will iterate through the values in `$D$3:$D$6` to see if they exist in the longer string, then it will return if it finds a match.  If no match is found it will return an error.

Answer (score 0):

`MATCH` accepts wildcards (for partial matches). You can try this formula in cell `B11` of the worksheet shown (and drag/fill down).

```
=INDEX(A$11:A$14,AGGREGATE(15,6,MATCH("*"&$D$11:$D$14&"*",$A11,0)*(ROW($D$11:$D$14)-ROW(D$11)+1),1))
```

So:

- `MATCH` is used to check if the `Word` partially matches any of the `Categories`. The `*` wildcard will match any character (including "no character"). It should return an array of `#N/A` for non-matches and `1` for matches.
- `ROW` is used to create a corresponding 1-based array of equal length.
- In the absence of a `FILTER` function, `AGGREGATE` is used to basically filter/exclude all errors. The `15` means only the first matching `Category` is returned.
- `INDEX` is used to retrieve the appropriate `Category` and complete the lookup.

If performance is really an issue, you might want to consider turning off automatic re-calculation, or using a VBA routine, or not storing the data in Excel.